OSLogStore API returns old logs, regardless of the specified timestamp
I am attempting to access logs from iOS's OSLogStore using Apple's provided API. To fetch these logs, I calculate a position based on a specific timestamp (date). However, the API consistently returns logs generated before the specified timestamp. I’m unsure how to resolve this issue.
Here is my code—I've explored following approaches for calculating the position, but the problem persists.
          let logStore = try OSLogStore(scope: .currentProcessIdentifier)
          let position = logStore.position(timeIntervalSinceEnd: -300)
          let entries = try logStore.getEntries(at: position) 

          let logStore = try OSLogStore(scope: .currentProcessIdentifier)
          let position = logStore.position(date: lastFetchTimeStamp)
          let entries = try logStore.getEntries(at: position)

